# Error in Window application when it will call WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I have developed window application and in that i am calling WCF at particular time interval however there is no error in inserting data into database through WCF but in log entry i am getting one error regarding WCF Endpoint as per below

> 2011-22-09 10:16>>Error: There was no endpoint listening at
>   *myserviceUrl(.svc)* that could accept the message. This is often
>   caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if
>   present, for more details.

app.config file as per below and i guess that probably error should be in below configuration

```
<client>
      <endpoint address="myserviceUrl(.svc)"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IApicaAzureMonitorAgentReceiverWCF"
        contract="Dashboard2WCFData.IApicaAzureMonitorAgentReceiverWCF"
        name="BasicHttpBinding_IApicaAzureMonitorAgentReceiverWCF" />
    </client>
```

Below is my (WCF)service's configuration..

```
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <section name="dataConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
  </configSections>
  <dataConfiguration defaultDatabase="Connectionstr"/>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Connectionstr" connectionString="myconnectionstring"/>   
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Please help me to sort out of this issues.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the endpoint is configured at the *service* side, not just your client.  In other words, if the client uses `myserviceUrl(.svc)`, the address needs to be specified in the service's config file.

Based on the error message you got, try this in the service's config file:

```
<endpoint address="myserviceUrl(.svc)"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IApicaAzureMonitorAgentReceiverWCF"
    contract="Dashboard2WCFData.IApicaAzureMonitorAgentReceiverWCF"
    name="BasicHttpBinding_IApicaAzureMonitorAgentReceiverWCF" />
```

Note that you'll need to ensure your service has the appropriate binding section named "BasicHttpBinding_IApicaAzureMonitorAgentReceiverWCF".

If you need a more thorough example, post your service's config file and we'll help you out.

**UPDATE**
Add an endpoint section, and a binding section if you have any values set to other than the default values:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<services>
    <service name="myServiceName">
     <endpoint address="myserviceUrl(.svc)"
               binding="basicHttpBinding"
               bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IApicaAzureMonitorAgentReceiverWCF"
               contract="Dashboard2WCFData.IApicaAzureMonitorAgentReceiverWCF"
               name="BasicHttpBinding_IApicaAzureMonitorAgentReceiverWCF"/>
     <endpoint name="mexHttpBinding"
               contract="IMetadataExchange"
               binding="mexHttpBinding"
               address="mex" />
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IApicaAzureMonitorAgentReceiverWCF" />
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

In the `<binding name=""` section is where you'd set the values for the binding.  If you don't do this (and don't specify the section in the endpoint's bindingConfiguration attribute) WCF will use the default values for basicHttpBinding.

**NOTE:** With WCF 4.0 and later, you actually don't need to specify an endpoint (or create a .svc file if hosting under IIS), as WCF will supply a default endpoint based on the URI of the service.  See [A Developer's Introduction to Windows Communication Foundation 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354381.aspx) for details on this and other new features in 4.0.

Comment: I have posted my service's config file in my question please check it however there is no binding section in that...

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example (added to your service config) for declaring the binding and endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify in address attribute the whole virtual path 
for example http://localhost/yousite/myservice.svc

Comment: I had just made it private, assume that there will be Full path

Comment: The error appears to be originating from the service, not the client.  Most likely Arun needs to update his service's config file per my answer below.